# Django migration duplicate operation

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm using `Django` for the backend of my application and everything is fine except a little problem with my migrations.

I'm using a custom User model by inheriting from `AbstractUser` and I have something like the following :

```py
class User(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"

    # Fields and methods here
    # ...
```

which results in this part of the migration in my `0001_initial.py` migration file :

```py
options={
  'verbose_name': 'User',
  'verbose_name_plural': 'Users',
  'abstract': False,
},
```

The thing is, when I run `makemigrations` later on, it creates an automatic migration with this little part in it :

```py
migrations.AlterModelOptions(
  name='user',
  options={'verbose_name': 'User'},
),
```

I do not understand why it tries to apply this modification a second time.
Can someone help me ?

I could let it as it is but I try to keep my migration files as clean as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ! Since I haven't been able to understand what was going on, I decided to try deleting all the migrations (I'm not yet in production so I could !) and generate them back.

It ended up with this part for my User model :

```py
options={
  'verbose_name': 'User',
},
```

Which is what I already had but...eh.

The good thing is that running `makemigrations` after that no longer generate weird things.